# Reputation not added?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation

On [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com) today I received an upvote and a question accepted but haven't been awarded any rep. I answered the question from my mobile and I thought it was just a caching issue after my rep didn't change. It's been several hours now and even shows a 0 next to the accept.

Is this a bug?

[image: Snippet of current reputation tab]

*Update:* I just checked this question and I have now received two upvotes but only one is showing up underneath my reputation tab.

Answer (score 4):

You [made that answer community wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/15324469/revisions) when you posted it. You cannot gain further reputation from community wiki posts. If it was made community wiki by accident, you will need to flag the answer for moderator attention to have the status removed. However, I don't believe removing it will cause the previous events to then gain reputation (just as a post becoming community wiki doesn't zero out the previous events).

Comment: I believe removing wiki from a post will result in gaining all the "lost" reputation.

Comment: @LoremIpsum That doesn't make any sense. We don't lose already-gained rep when one of our posts becomes CW (whether we make it CW or it becomes CW from editing). Do you have evidence to support the claim that we gain reputation associated with events that occurred on a question when it *was* CW?

Answer (score 2):

You made the answer community wiki. You don't gain/lose reputation from community wiki posts.

Comment: Wow I must have accidentally done that on my mobile. Thanks